# Java Locks and Conditions error?

Tags: java

In this class I have methods in a LockResourceManager class that request the resource and release the resource. However in the class I have an error that appears on the line at the top

```
final int[] buffer = new T();
```

The error that appears is

`Type Mismatch: cannot convert from T to int[]`.

This is the only error appearing in the code so I dont know what to do to fix this as I don't understand what is wrong with that line.

```
public class LockResourceManager<T> extends BasicResourceManager implements ResourceManager {
final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
final Condition notFull = lock.newCondition();
final Condition notEmpty = lock.newCondition();
final int[] buffer = new T();

public LockResourceManager(Resource resource, int maxUses) {
    super(resource, maxUses);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void requestResource(int priority) throws ResourceError{
    lock.lock();
    try {
    while (NO_OF_PRIORITIES == buffer.length) notFull.await();
    buffer[NO_OF_PRIORITIES] = priority;
    NO_OF_PRIORITIES = (NO_OF_PRIORITIES+1)%buffer.length;
    NO_OF_PRIORITIES++;
    notEmpty.signal();
    } finally {
    lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: `final int[] buffer = new T();` -- what this line is supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your class declaration, I guess that T is just a generic type and not a defined class; thus you can not do `final int[] buffer = new T();`

Maybe you should write a class with a method `public int[] toBuffer()`, so that you can replace your faulty line with `final int[] buffer = new YourClass().toBuffer();`, and don't to update the first line like following:
 `public class LockResourceManager<YourClass> extends BasicResourceManager implements ResourceManager`

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the  `BasicResourceManager` class or the  `ResourceManager` interface but the compiler error is quite simple: your `buffer` variable is a array of `int` while the value of `T` is pretty much anything you can come up with since it's a generic (`<T>` in the class declaration).

By reading your code, I realized you only use it to store other `int`, so you should declare it as: `final int[] buffer = new int[10];`

Keep in mind, however, that since it's a array, it has a fixed size. It seems like you're using it as some sort of hash collection, so you should use a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` so it can grow as needed.

Comment: There is no such thing as `<int, int>` - you mean `<Integer, Integer>`.

Comment: Also, you do protect your variables against redefinition by setting them as `final`s but you should also scope them with `private`s, `protected`s or `public`s  otherwise the default to `protected`, meaning any other class in the package and any subclass can use them.

Comment: Thaks, @Jägermeister, that's exactly it.

Answer (score 0):

T is a generic type (as you definied it `LockResourceManager<T>`) which mean you can't do a `new T();` (I don't even understand how the code can compile this).

You need to do `LockResourceManager<T extends Yourclass>` and instantiate a `YourClass`.

Also you can't cast an `Object` to a `int[]`, even if it's a `Integer[ARR_SIZE]` (but you can do the conversion manually).

I think you might want

```
private final int[] buffer;

public LockResourceManager(Resource resource, int maxUses) {
   super(resource, maxUses);
   buffer = new int[maxUses];
}
```

If you want your bufer to limit its size to `maxUses`

Answer (score 0):

```
final int[] buffer = new T();
```

Above line is completely invalid. Following are the reasons:

1. Here T is a generic type so it must be stored in T or its parent class.

   `final T buffer = new T();`
2. You are invoking the constructor of class T and a constructor can never return an array object.
3. If you want to get it to int[], either must be some factory method not the constructor.
4. Even if the factory method is used, you cannot use it directly with T as T can be anything. You must define the parent of T which contains this method. For example,

*

```
public class LockResourceManager<T extends SomeParentClass> {
//...
}
class SomeParentClass{
//...
//factory method declaration
}
```

*